# VBA How to access a listbox by name excel-2010

Tags: vba, excel-2010

Below is my VBA code to get a selected item from a listbox. I want to send the name of the listbox as a string then access the list box that way since I can't access the listbox directly because this code is in a seperate module from my worksheet source code.

So what I am asking is how do you access a listbox by string.
For example, instead of

```
Worksheets("sheet1").ListBox1
```

I want something like

```
Worksheets("sheet1")."ListBox1"
```

So I can reuse this function as long as I have the name of the listbox

Code below

```
Public Function getListBoxSelection(listBox As MSForms.listBox) As String
    Dim colCount As Integer
    Dim I As Long
    Dim selectedItem As String

    If listBox.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        For I = 0 To (listBox.ColumnCount - 1)
             selectedItem = selectedItem & listBox.column(I)
        Next I
    End If
    getListBoxSelection = selectedItem
End Function
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Worksheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object